# Lyapunov Function for Nonlinear Systems

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, control-theory, nonlinear-system, lyapunov-functions

Since there is no systematic method to find Lyapunov functions, how should I approach the question shown below to find corresponding Lyapunov function? With $\alpha<0$

$$\begin{align}  x_1'&=-3x_2\\
    x_2'&=x_1-\alpha(2x_2^3-x_2)\\     \end{align}
    $$

Comment: This system is locally but not globally stable. You can obtain a Lyapunov  by solving the algebraic Lyapunov equation for the linearization i.e. $V=x^TPx$ where $P$ is a symmetric positive definite $2\times 2$ matrix that solves $PA+A^TP=-I$ with $A=\left[\matrix{0 & -3\\ 1 & \alpha}\right]$.

Comment: But linearization gives only state of local stability. We cannot say system is globally unstable by linearization, can we? @CTNT

Comment: No you cannot tell if the linearization is stable. But you can find another $V$ that grows to infinity when $|x_2|$ is large enough.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @CTNT proposed first linearize the system at the origin to obtain the system matrix $\boldsymbol{A}$ of the linearized system

$$\boldsymbol{A}=\begin{bmatrix}0 & -3\\1 & \alpha \end{bmatrix}.$$

The linearized system is asymptotically stable (also called Hurwitz) as the characteristic polynomial is equal to

$$\chi(s)=s^2-\alpha s +3.$$

By the Hurwitz criterion for second order polynomials (all coefficients have to be positive; note, that $-\alpha>0$), we know that the linearized system is asymptotically stable. By the indirect method of Lyapunov (as we have a polynomial right-hand side of the differential equation system all conditions for linearization are fulfilled in a neighbourhood of the origin) we know that the origin of the nonlinear system is also asymptotically stable.

By the Lyapunov's converse theorems we also know that there exists a unique symmetric positive definite matrix $\boldsymbol{P}$ as a solution to the Lyapunov equation

$$\boldsymbol{PA}+\boldsymbol{A^TP}=-\boldsymbol{Q},$$

in which $\boldsymbol{Q}$ is a positive definite matrix. As @CTNT proposed $\boldsymbol{Q}=\boldsymbol{I}$ is often chosen. If you solve the system you will have found a Lyapunov function for asymptotic stability for the origin.

An alternative approach uses the standard Lyapunov candidate function

$$V=\dfrac{1}{2}\left[x_1^2+kx_2^2\right]$$
$$ \implies \dot{V}=x_1\dot{x_1}+kx_2\dot{x}_2=-3x_1x_2+kx_2\left[ x_1-\alpha\left(2x_2^3-x_2 \right)\right]$$
$$=-3x_1x_2+kx_1x_2-\alpha k\left(2x_2^4-x_2^2 \right)$$

Now, set $k=3$ to eliminate the cross-product term to obtain

$$\dot{V}=-\alpha k(2x_2^4-x_2^2)=\alpha k x_2^2(1-2x_2^2).$$

For $1-2x_2^2>0 \implies |x_2|<\dfrac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$ we know that

$$\dot{V}\leq 0.$$

By using Barbashin and Krasovskii Theorem in the neighbourhood $D=\{x\in \mathbb{R}^2|x_1^2+x_2^2<1/2\}$ of the origin we see that no solution can stay inside the set $S=\{x\in D\,|\,\dot{V}=0\}=\{x\in D\,|\,x_2=0\}$, other than the trivial solution $x_1=0$ and $x_2=0$ (verify by plugging this into the differential equation). This implies that the origin is asymptotically stable (which we already knew by the indirect method of Lyapunov). This method does not require to solve the Lyapunov equation but at the same time has the downside that a more advanced stability theorem needs to be applied.

Looking at the [phase portait](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=StreamPlot%5B%7B-3*y,x%2B10*(2*y%5E3-y)%7D,%7Bx,-5,5%7D,%7By,-5,5%7D%5D) (for a specific $\alpha=-10$) suggests that the system has an unstable limit cycle which makes it very unlikely that the origin is globally aymptotically stable for arbitrary $\alpha$. Note, that this is not a rigoruous statement it is just an observation. If you can prove that there exists a limit cycle then you can make this statement rigoruous.

Comment: How could you determine Lyapunov candidate function? In other systems we cannot use the function you took in this problem, I suppose. For example if we have a system like this: $x_1'=-x_1^3+x_2^6$ and $x_2'=x_1^6+x_2$ we cannot use the function you took.

Comment: The standard guess is always $V(x) = x_1^2+x_2^2$ if that fails I would try $V(x) = x_1^2+kx_2^2$. As you already pointed out this will not always work. It is just a method to quickly guess a Lyapunov function. Using the Lyapunov equation will guarantee for a system matrix which is Hurwitz, that the $P$ you determine will really lead to a $V=x^TPx$ which is a Lyapunov function for asymptotic stability for the origin of the nonlinear system.

Comment: Thank you that clears everything up but eigenvalues of the second example should be 0 and 1, I think.

Comment: Yes, you are right, don't know where I got the 2 from :D.